# Connect to local MySQL server without sudo

Tags: mysql, sudo

This command:

`mysql -uroot -p`

Gives the following error:

`ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (13)`

But running the same with sudo privileges, works:

`sudo mysql -uroot -p`

My MySQL Server installation is a custom one, as i needed the 5.1 version, so i downloaded the RPM from the official website, converted it to deb using alien, and installed it with dpkg. The file named: */var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock* exists, but it's owner is the *mysql* user.

**Please, how could i get rid of the sudo requirement?**

Ubuntu 14.04
MySQL Server 5.1.73
MySQL Client 5.5.37

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connect to mysql server without sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37239970/connect-to-mysql-server-without-sudo)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to change the permissions to /var/lib/mysql/ and the sock file to let it be readable by other users than root. You can try this one:

`sudo chmod -R 755 /var/lib/mysql/`

Comment: Didn't help. The socket file was already with all permissions to all users.

Comment: Ok, just try to analize all of the directories down in the path of the socket file, they need to have o+rx and the sock file too (it's not a good idea to make it modifiable by others). You can also try to remove mysql.sock and then restart mysqld, the file should be created by the daemon with proper privileges.

Comment: Ok, restarted the service, i mean i rebooted, and now it works. :)

Comment: `chmod 755 /run/mysqld ` worked for me. The socket was fine but the directory it was in was not readable by anyone other than `mysql`.

Answer (score -4):

I don't think you can since the user you specify with the -u option is root. To be root you need sudo. You can try creating another user. That way you shouldn't need sudo.

Comment: There is no connection between the mysql user `root` and the operating system's `root` or `sudo`. It's 100% possible for a regular system user to connect to mysql as `root`.