# Connect to mysql server without sudo

Tags: mysql, sudo

The command:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

gives the error:

```
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

But running sudo privileges, works:

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

**Is it possible to get rid of the sudo requirement** because it prevents me from opening the database in intellij? I tried the following as in the answer to this question [Connect to local MySQL server without sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24479868/3599535):

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/lib/mysql/
```

which did not help. The above question has a different error thrown

Comment: sudo chmod 777 /var/run/mysqld/

Comment: Only the path was wrong to me: it WORKS on /usr/sbin/mysqld
Changing OWNER allows normal users log without sudo. Sudo chown you:you mysqld

Answer (score 185, accepted):

Only the root user needs sudo requirement to login to mysql. I resolved this by creating a new user and granting access to the required databases:

```
CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database_name.* TO 'newuser'@'localhost';
```

now `newuser` can login without sudo requirement:

```
mysql -u newuser -p
```

Comment: To anyone wondering what the password may be, it's the string after `IDENTIFIED BY`, in this case simply 'password'

Comment: Just a heads up: when you connect don't put a space after the `-p` option. For example do: `mysql -u newuser -ppassword` (no space!)

Comment: @TaimoorAhmad no, just put `-p` on its own. Then it prompts you for the password, and the password you then type is not displayed on-screen for others to see.

Answer (score 99):

You need to change algorithm. Following work for me,

```
mysql > ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '';
mysql > FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: It helped me too. Suddenly, after restart I started getting the Access Denied for user root@localhost. This solution help me to connect with mysql

Comment: This worked for me when I was only able to log into mysql as root when I was signed in as root.  Once I assigned root a blank password I was able to log out, log back in with the blank password, then use the same command to use my desired password .

Answer (score 77):

You can use the same ROOT user, or a NEW_USER and remove the SUDO privileges. Below example shows how to remove connect using ROOT, without SUDO.

Connect to MY-SQL using SUDO

```
sudo mysql -u root
```

Delete the current Root User from the User Table

```
DROP USER 'root'@'localhost';
```

Create a new ROOT user (You can create a different user if needed)

```
CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '';
```

Grant permissions to new User (ROOT)

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Flush privileges, so that the Grant tables get reloaded immediately. ([Why do we need to flush privileges?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36464093/4388776))

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Now it's all good. Just in case, check whether a new root user is created.

```
SELECT User,Host FROM mysql.user;

+------------------+-----------+
| User             | Host      |
+------------------+-----------+
| root             | %         |
| debian-sys-maint | localhost |
| mysql.session    | localhost |
| mysql.sys        | localhost |
+------------------+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Exit mysql. (Press CTRL + Z). Connect to MySQL without SUDO

```
mysql -u root
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Worked for me. The only change I made was replacing '%' with 'localhost'

Comment: Brilliant! This should be the accepted answer. Exactly what I was looking for as you explained it all in the well documented steps!

Answer (score 45):

first login to your mysql with sudo.

then use this code to change "plugin" coloumn value from "unix_socket" or "auth_socket" to "mysql_native_password" for root user.

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET plugin = 'mysql_native_password' WHERE user = 'root' AND plugin IN ('unix_socket', 'auth_socket');

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

finally restart mysql service. that's it.

if you want more info, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28068155/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-yes-after-new-instal) link

UPDATE:

In new versions of mysql or mariadb you can use :

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password USING PASSWORD('your-password');
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: plugin value was 'auth_socket' in my case.

Comment: `sudo service mysql restart` to restart.

Comment: This was the only one of all the listed answers that worked for me (MariaDB v15.1).

Answer (score 12):

I have solved this problem using following commands.

```
CREATE USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'username'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Here, 
 `username` = any user name you like.

and `password` = any password you like.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the below query:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

This query is enough.

Comment: This answer should be a solution as well. THANKS!!!

Answer (score 3):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47567940/1877106) needs to be slightly adapted for mariaDB instead of mysql.

First login as root using sudo:

```
$ sudo mysql -uroot
```

Then alter the mariadb root user:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password USING PASSWORD('mypassword');
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

From now on sudo is not longer needed:

```
$ mysql -uroot -p
```

Version used:
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.4.13-MariaDB, for osx10.15 (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Answer (score 2):

Login to mysql with sudo:
`sudo mysql -u root -p`

After that Delete current root@localhost account:

```
~ MariaDB [(none)]> DROP USER 'root'@'localhost';
~ MariaDB [(none)]> CREATE USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
~ MariaDB [(none)]> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
~ MariaDB [(none)]> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the comment of the question you answer you referenced, it reads

> Ok, just try to analyze all of the directories down in the path of the
>   socket file, they need to have o+rx and the sock file too (it's not a
>   good idea to make it modifiable by others).
>
> You can also try to remove mysql.sock and then restart mysqld, the
>   file should be created by the daemon with proper privileges.

This seemed to work for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24479915/3599535)(the one you said you looked at) so it may work for you as well

Comment: How do I do that? The question I referred has a different error thrown

Comment: Thats no reason to downvote!! : tahe a look in the /etc/mysql/my.cnf file and diable this: #plugin-load-add = auth_socket.so and restart databse, or read this how to start mysql without password https://www.liberiangeek.net/2014/10/reset-root-password-mariadb-centos-7/

Answer (score -11):

The error Message:

**"ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'"**

means that the Server not allow the connect for this user and not that mysql cant access the socket.

try this to solve the problem:

Login in your DB

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

then make these modifications:

```
MariaDB []>use mysql;
MariaDB [mysql]>update user set plugin=' ' where User='root';
MariaDB [mysql]>flush privileges;
MariaDB [mysql]>exit
```

try login again without sudo

Comment: I tried that and now I can't even login with sudo. Might have to reinstall mysql :(

Comment: Congrats on making an answer that not only it fails to solve the problem, but also makes it worse.